# Can you dynamically create the arguments for the zip() function in python 2?

Tags: python-2.7, zip

I am passing in a variable number of lists in *args to a function. What I'd like to accomplish is to pass this args to zip().

```
def amv(db, *args):
    x = zip(args)
    return x
```

I would like to avoid the following:

```
if len(args) == 1:
    x = zip(args[1])
elif len(args) == 2:
    x = zip(args[1], args[2])
...etc.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Erm... you almost have it.

```
x = zip(*args)
```

Comment: Great! Thanks. It turns out I need to fill out any short-filled lists (to make them all the same length) in order to avoid zip() truncating at the lowest length of all of the lists. In this case, do I have to create a tuple of the new lists? Tuples can't be dynamically generated so I guess I'm stuck.